# Highstock How to remove the cross icon in Range selector text box in IE

Tags: highcharts

On the highStock [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/allbuttonsenabled-true/)

If open in IE and click in the range selector text box to change dates. A little cross symbol appears. How to remove this behavior.

This is what I am talking `about` 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a small CSS trick to solve this problem;

```
.highcharts-range-selector::-ms-clear {
    display: none;
}
```

[::-ms-clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx) reference from MSDN.